# How do I create an news page in SharePoint 2010 and have feature articles on the home page?

Tags: content-query-web-part, intranet

I have been tasked with creating the home page of our department's intranet page. I am a beginner admin for SharePoint and need help with the following:

My department needs a news page which will have articles written by the Managers and VP's of the various divisions of our department. They are looking for something similar to this news page: https://www.marshfieldclinic.org/news. They want:

-The articles to show the publish date, author and author's email. 
-For employees to be able to see or be able to search all past articles
-For 2 - 3 of the most recent articles (feature articles) to be displayed in a web part on our home page 
-For the feature article to update automatically based on the publish date.

To meet their needs, I am thinking I have to use a blog template or Publishing Site followed by a Content Query Web Part on the home page to display the feature articles. Again, I am a beginner user, so will take ANY input on how to use make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about using either Blog Template or Publishing Site. I don't have much experience on Blog Template but on Publishing Site, you can create a Content Type (let's say Article Content Type) with all the required fields. And then create a Page Layout based on this content type, you can design the page layout to show the required fields and apply styling as you want.

About employees to see all articles, you can drop a List View Web Part (from Pages Library), filter it to only show Article Content Type pages and apply styles on that. About searching you can create a Search Scope to target only Article Content Type and add this Search Scope to your publishing site's search drop down.

About showing recent, you can create Content Query or List View Web Part to show only 2-3 results and sort descending on Created field (so that new one's come to the top). Apply styles and design to this web part.

All individual tasks you can search on the internet to find much information on how to.

Comment: Thanks! Your input on CQWP gave me a better understanding how to use it. I am going to try your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new publishing site called news. You can create new pages based at the article page lay-out. At the site you want to show the news articles you can add a content query web part.

This will be pretty basic but you have enough modification options. You can create your own content type based at the article page and add new columns.

The content query web part can have a custom itemstyle to show the news articles in any way you define it. For example with a image, title and short description.

Check these resources about itemstyle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551040.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb850574(v=office.12).aspx

http://www.bentedder.com/itemstyle-xsl-in-sharepoint-2010-a-guide-for-designers/

Original post:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0b4bad1b-e700-4ca1-9d5e-0ce8ceb2b941/how-to-create-news-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010

Another link that i was using while i was creating news webpart:
https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/display-news-pages-with-cqwp-%E2%80%93-part-i/

Comment: Thanks! This is the guidance I needed - the additional resouces give me great details. I am going to try your advice.